# How to delete the line which matches the string shared in array

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file which consist of text like below

```
compile_tool/opt/CSDTK/bin/chipgen/Modem2G/toolpool/plugins/Calib/libcalibplugin.so
compile_tool/opt/CSDTK/bin/chipgen/Modem2G/toolpool/plugins/Calib/libcalibplugin.dill
compile_tool/opt/CSDTK/bin/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/Rakefile.pg
compile_tool/opt/mingw32_3.4.4/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/mmsystem.c
compile_tool/opt/mingw32_3.4.4/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/winnt.h
compile_tool/opt/CSDTK/bin/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-2.1.2/test/test_xchar.HEX
```

I want to delete the line which is having file extension .so , .dill ,.pg and .HEX. i have tried below code but didn't make out.

```
#! /bin/bash
array=(.a .so .bin.ihex .dll .exe .gem .bin .png .HEX)
for a in "${array[@]}"
do 
sed -i -e "/\$a\b/d" copyright
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `sed` supports the `\|` `(or)` operator in regex, would you please try:

```
array=(.a .so .bin.ihex .dll .exe .gem .bin .png .HEX)
pat="$(IFS='|'; echo "${array[*]}" | sed -e 's/|/\\|/g' -e 's/\./\\./g')"
sed "/\($pat\)\$/d" copyright
```

- It concatenates the array elements and generates a pattern string which looks like: `\.a\|\.so\|\.bin\.ihex\|...`.
- Then the line `sed "/\($pat\)\$/d" text` deletes the lines which match the pattern.

Please note that your array elements and your text `"line which is having file extension .so , .dill ,.pg and .HEX"` may disagree. I have used your `array` as is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `sed` once for each extension, you can use something like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
grep -F -v "${array[*]}" copyright
```

If its output looks good, redirect it to a file and change its name to `copyright` (and restore `IFS` if necessary).

Comment: @oguzismail : This would also delete a line, say, `abc.sox.txt`. The extensions in the `array` need to be matched at the end of the file name. Maybe we have to transform `array` first by adding a `$` at the end, and then omit `-F` from _grep_.

Comment: @user1934428 That's true, I just assumed OP didn't have such lines in their input. To cover those cases, as well as appending `$` to elements, we need to escape `.`s too; otherwise `.so$` for instance would match `abc.iso` too.

Comment: You're right. Maybe a more sensible and in the end more flexible approach would be to have files.txt contain egrep patterns instead of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the idea discussed with Oguz Ismail based on his answer:

No matter whether you use `grep -e` or sed to identify the files being kept, the problem is that in both cases, the elements of your `array` are interpreted as a regular expression. For instance, you have one array element `.a`, and as regexp, this would mean that it will match any file containing the letter 'a' except at the **start** of the file name. Hence, the line `main.c` would also be matched by the pattern `.a`.

One possibility is to use wildcard matching instead of regexp matching, but this means that you need to explicitly loop through your `array`: For instance, to test whether the line `$line` is going to be deleted or should be kept, you would have to do something like:

```
line_matches_pat=no
for pat in "${array[@]}"
do
  if [[ $line == *$pat ]]
  then
    line_matches_pat=yes
    break
  fi
done
```

If `$line_matches_pat` equals `yes`, the line matches one of the patterns in the array.

IMO a more sensible and flexible approach would be to store in `array` not the extensions of the files, but regular expressions for the files you are interested in. This allows you one day to put into the list something like *filenames containing the string `error_` and having the extension `.c`*. When you do this, you could use an approach similar to the solution suggested by @oguzismail, but of course you can't use `-F` with grep anymore:

```
grep -E -v "${array[*]}" copyright
```

This turns on extended regular expressions. Drop the `-E` if you are fine with simple regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @tshiono suggested but using `printf` to construct pattern

```
printf -v pat '\%s\|' ${array[@]}
sed "/${pat%*'\|'}/d" copyright
```